# Collision detection in pygame. Error: no attribute 'rect'

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision-detection

New to pygame, writing a little code to try and detect collisions. Here is a small test file I wrote up to demonstrate the error. It instantiates two sprites, and tries to detect collision between them

```
import pygame

class Box(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
class Circle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

box = Box()
circle = Circle()
group = pygame.sprite.Group()
group.add(circle)
pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(box, group)
```

However this returns an error:

```
default_sprite_collide_func = sprite.rect.colliderect
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Box' object has no attribute 'rect'
```

I'm not really sure what I should be doing to remedy the situation. How can I detect collision between two sprites in pygame?

NOTE: edited to include proposed solution from an answer. I'm not making a new question since I'm still getting a similar error.

Comment: Are you certain you're supposed to pass the Classes to ```spritecollideany()```?  Should you be instantiating those classes?  i.e. ```box = Box()```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [spritecolllideany](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollideany) function takes as parameters `(sprite, group)`, i.e. the first parameter is a sprite *instance* and the second parameter is a [sprite group](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) (which contains one or more sprite *instances*).

In your example code, your are passing *classes*; it is equivalent to:

```py
pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(Box, Circle) # passing the class objects, oops!
```

The error message might be a little confusing but it is giving some good clues about what is going on: it's essentially saying that the `Box` *class* has no attribute named `rect` (if an *instance* had been passed in, instead of the error saying `type object 'Box'...`, it would instead say `'Box' object...`).

You'll probably need something more like:

```py
box = Box() # create an instance
circle = Circle()
group = pygame.sprite.Group() # create a group with a sprite in it
group.add(circle)
hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(box, group)
if hit:
  ... # there was a collision...
```

Note that your subclasses aren't calling the base `Sprite` class `__init__` method, which you probably want to do. Also, your sprite subclasses don't currently do anything - you'll want to make them draw an image, for example.

I know you mentioned that your sample code is just a trimmed down example, so maybe you're already doing both of these things in your actual code. If not, the [chimp example](https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/ChimpLineByLine.html) walks you through some of that.

Comment: This code still does not work.

Comment: I would note that it also produces the exact same error. To be clear, in my actual code I did something like this, I just reproduced a minimal example to demonstrate the issue. Edited question to rule out this answer.

Comment: Please double check that it is producing the *exact* same error - if the problem is that you made the changes I suggested but are getting an AttributeError with a message like "Box object has no attribute rect" (as opposed to the original msg about "type object Box"), then the error is saying exactly what you need: your sprite needs a 'rect' attribute. The docs for spritecollideany (linked above) say that you need to either provide the 'collided' callback or all the sprites involved need a 'rect' attribute.

Comment: Ok, I think you're right.